# Ubuntu and Docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I want to use a volume mounted on my container but it throws the next error when trying to run:

> docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source
> path '/var/skeeter/templates': mkdir /var/skeeter: read-only file
> system.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-13-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /var/container/skeeter/templates

WORKDIR /project
ADD ./target/skeeter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar skeeter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

EXPOSE 8080

CMD java -jar skeeter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And this is the run cmd:

> docker run -t -p 8080:8080 -v
> /var/skeeter/templates:/var/container/skeeter/templates --name
> skeeter-docker-container skeeter-docker-image:latest

This is the CMD output when i'm checking the directories permissions:

```
ls -l /var/skeeter/
total 4 drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 ago 11 16:45 templates

ls -ld /var/skeeter/
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 ago 11 16:45 /var/skeeter/
```

Update:
I created a new Volume and used its name at -v parameter and it runned, but java app cannot find files inside the directory

Comment: Have you tried using read-only? https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-read-only-volume

Comment: My read of that error message is that (a) the host directory `/var/skeeter/templates` doesn't exist (I think even `/var/skeeter` doesn't exist), and (b) that the filesystem containing `/var/skeeter` (the host's `/var` most likely) is mounted read-only.  Are you running those two `ls -l` commands from a root shell on the host?

Comment: @David Maze yes, I'm running these ls commands from a root shell on the host

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was just a permissions issue.
I moved the source directory to /home/myuser/directory/ and worked.

Comment: Come on guys! As i'm new with this world it's probably to fail in the right way to solve it. I'm really open to other ideas instead of just say "not usefull answer"